# css vertical align li and border of the div

Tags: html, css, border, vertical-alignment

Hi i am trying to center vertically some li
But as i put a border-top and border-bottom, it doesn t work anymore.
I tried to change the value of 100 everywhere (more and less, combination,...) but i cant make it work

Thanks all

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=tester" /> Some text</li>
        <li> Some text</li>
        <li>333</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
    ul li {
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    }

    ul li img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-top: 1px solid #444444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgyakeu3/

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li {
display: block;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
text-align :center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kartik_bhalala/89amryhw/

Answer (score 1):

Height doesn't apply to `inline` elements. You should make the `li`s `inline-block`. Also you should override the browser defaults for margin, padding etc.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgyakeu3/1/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked.
But why the need to override the browser defaults?

Comment: @FredericCS if you remove the `*{margin:0}` from the fiddle you'll notice that browser adds margin for li for defaulit kind of list rendering which will wreck or CSS when we use it for other purposes like a menu... it's a common thing. There are style sheets like normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve? Is this the case? https://jsfiddle.net/pgyakeu3/2/

Since you know exactly the height value of your elements, this can be acomplished this way:

```
ul {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
ul li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div {
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border-top:1px solid #444444;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
}
```